# Spark java program to write dataframe into snowflake table

Tags: java, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Unable to write spark dataframe into snowflake table.

21/06/07 09:04:05 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter to /static/sql.
21/06/07 09:04:05 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7690638d{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/06/07 09:04:05 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
21/06/07 09:04:12 ERROR SnowflakeWriter: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 370001:4107598406; incident 4986515.
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:99)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:410)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:373)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:197)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:149)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:531)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:204)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.execute(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:239)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:261)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:261)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$3.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:283)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

21/06/07 09:04:12 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0
21/06/07 09:04:12 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Do you have logs available from Snowflake? Apparently a query was ran with an error -- and if that error didn't show up at the Scala side, it might probably be accesible from within Snowflake. It will also help if you share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Internal error `370001` is permissions/auth related.  Can you run the example with the connection properties you used in your code that resulted in an error?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
public class SnowflakeJDBCExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:snowflake://xy12345.snowflakecomputing.com/";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("user", "peter");
    properties.put("password", "test");
    properties.put("account", "xy12345");
    properties.put("warehouse", "mywh");
    properties.put("db", "mydb");
    properties.put("schema", "public");

    // get connection
    System.out.println("Create JDBC connection");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, properties);
    System.out.println("Done creating JDBC connection\n");
    // create statement
    System.out.println("Create JDBC statement");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Done creating JDBC statement\n");
    // create a table
    System.out.println("Create my_variant_table table");
    statement.executeUpdate("create or replace table my_variant_table(json VARIANT)");
    statement.close();
    System.out.println("Done creating demo table\n");

    connection.close();
    System.out.println("Close connection\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was database privilege issue, only read access was given.